Running multiple instance of a sandboxed (isolated) application?
I have a client that wants me to use an Authenticator App that I already use for work AND home. Currently I'm using Shelter to provide work and home, but it's limited to those two "profiles". The functionality provided is fine, but I need something that provides more profiles or units of isolation?
Is there any work around?
Magisk is allowed. The phone is also rooted.
